# Is there an internal equivalent to fail2ban?

Tags: linux, ssh, brute-force

`fail2ban` is a protection against brute-force that locks a user out after a definable maximum failed login-attempts.

But if a user already has access to a server with another username already fail2ban is not active anymore from the inside, so you have infinite tries to brute-force with

```
slogin otheruser@localhost
```

into another useraccount.

- Is there a tool I could install on linux that **kicks** a user after a number of failed **local ssh-login** attempts?
- And how do I have to configure it so a user gets kicked after 10 false attempts?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php) for this also. It is very configurable. In this case, you would need to write a new filter to watch your auth logs. You can use the `<HOST>` shortcut to match usernames, too, since those ought to conform to "hostname" parameters. You would also need to write a new action to perform the kick. The [fail2ban manual](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8) has lots of good information to get you started.

As another example of extending fail2ban, I set up a filter to watch fail2ban's own logs. If any 1 host triggers any combination of bans more than 4 times in a month, they get a month-long ban.

Comment: I altered the question. The main reason I ask here and don't just RTFM is because I get overwhelmed by the amount of information in the manual :) So how would I have to change the default configuration of fail2ban?

Answer (score 3):

if you already have fail2ban deployed, go with it, otherwise and for larger setups, [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/) is always good for host-based intrusion detection.

Maybe a start: [Looking for the best way to log all "sudo su - someuser".](http://osdir.com/ml/ossec-list/2011-10/msg00139.html)

---

so kid, you neva herd 'bout the **BOFH**, didnt ya? otherwise you'd know about the [**"Bastard Operation Control Center"**](http://bofh.ntk.net/BOFH/images/b14-screen.gif); another tool to suggest would be a [**LART**](http://bastardadmin.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/enhanced-buzz-12841-1306166195-5.jpg)

related:

- [BOFH in a Nutshell](http://www.bofhcam.org/co-larters/bofh-nutshell/index.html) by O'REALLY
- [LART Pocket Reference](http://www.bofhcam.org/co-larters/lart-reference/) by O'REALLY

Answer (score 1):

sligtly OT: **SU** would be a reason to kick a user forever; **use SUDO** instead, so you dont have to give out the root-password.

this is what we do:

- we have a lot of different developers on our servers
- we have a limitted set of tasks that needs SUDO-rights, like services test/restart, cleanups etc
- we have a simple task-shell for users to select and perform these commands  via bash (its called `bosh` : bastard operator shell :); this also prevents stupid things like RESTART instead of RELOAD or a forgotten CONFIG_TEST before a RELOAD
- those without shell-accounts can execute some tasks via hudson
- we have a special workshop for that users and additional, up-to-date documents available in a wiki
- ALL sudo/su attempts are logged and reported
- if one shell-user tries to su or sudo he must report WHY and face the LART
- each shell-user has signed a "i know i'm doomed if i try to h4xor something" agreement
- we let every user know that we monitor their steps